# Send a new packet without waiting for the previous packet reply

Tags: python, packet, scapy, reply

I have got a simple webserver set up with scapy, it waits for replies like so:

```
connreq = sniff(filter=connfilter, prn=handshake)
```

In the function *handshake* a handshake is carried out,  but I am having a certain problem, here is where:

```
answer = sr1(ip/synack, timeout = 4)
```

A synack is send and an answer awaits, if no answer is received within 4 seconds then the handshake will be terminated. However, for some reason, my function handshake will only carry out one at a time if I have multiple clients, because scapy **waits for an answer of the previous client**.

I don't want the scapy sniff function to wait, I want it to process a packet in any case, even if the previous packet is not processed yet.

I am familiar with threading the function, but how do I apply that to scapy? (or to the sniff function?)

Comment: Do you mean you don't want sniff function waiting on webserver side?

Comment: @m170897017 yes, I want it to handle multiple clients at the same time and not waiting for the last client to be 'finished'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
You can try `timeout` parameter in `sniff` function. I remembered there is such parameter.

```
connreq = sniff(filter=connfilter, prn=handshake, timeout=4)
```

2.
If method 1 doesn't work, you will have to use multi-process to handle this.

In server side,

```
import threading
def your_sniff_function():
    connreq = sniff(filter=connfilter, prn=handshake)
    # save sniff result to local file here

t = threading.Thread(target=your_sniff_function, args=[])
t.start()
t.join(timeout=4) # use timeout here to force termination
# you can start as many subthreads as you want here
```